# can a gofmt rewrite rule remove redundant argument types?

Tags: go

If you have code like: `func MyFunc(a int, b int)`

Can a gofmt rewrite rule change it to: `func MyFunc(a, b int)`

I tried: `gofmt -r "f(x t, y t) -> f(x, y t)" myfile.go`

But I get: `parsing pattern f(x t, y t)  at 1:5: expected ')', found 'IDENT' t`

I also tried: `gofmt -r "f(x int, y int) -> f(x, y int)" myfile.go`

But it gives a similar error for int instead of t

I have read the [gofmt documentation](http://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/). A web search didn't turn up anything helpful.

I am deliberately using single character identifiers to match expressions.

I suspect the problem may be in trying to match the type since it may not be regarded as an "expression"

Is it possible to do this with gofmt?

Comment: This might be a good request to add to the `-s` option though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not possible - because go fmt treat patter as "Expression", look at the http://golang.org/src/cmd/gofmt/rewrite.go parseExpr() function.

Go specification(http://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions) 
clearly says what "An expression specifies the computation of a value by applying operators and functions to operands."
so go fmt try to parse your pattern "f(x t, y t)" as function call, so instead of "t" it expects comma or parentheses.

you can not write pattern which will much "func MyFunc(a int, b int)" - because its function definition, not a valid go expression